# I need to run a script on a remote server, that has an oracle database on it

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, cmd

I have a script I am writing, that I am going to do a PSSession to a remote server, then connect to `sqlplus` and run an unlock user command. I am not sure if this can work, because I am wanting a user prompt box to pop up, and input that variable into the alter username command in `sqlplus`.

This is what I have tried locally first:

```
sqlplus sqlusername/123;
ACCEPT myVariable CHAR PROMPT 'Inputvalue: ';
ALTER USERNAME 'Inputvalue: ' ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Comment: Any ideas? I am decent at powershell when it comes to simple stuff, but going between powershell to sqlplus is blowing my mind. I also have never used sqlplus before.

Comment: Why do you have to run sqlplus on the remote server?

Comment: I don't have to, but I was unsure of how to connect any other way. also I am wanting to use this as a way for supervisors to unlock their users without having access to the server directly

Comment: I figured I could put the script on their computers and they could run it from their locations

Comment: If you are invoking the script from a local workstation and passing commands to a server for processing, you should get all inputs locally and then pass them to the server - pseudocode might be `GET-LOCKED-USERNAME AS A$; SEND-SERVER-MESSAGE TO SERVER SQLPLUS-SERVER WITH MESSAGE 'UNLOCK A$'`

Comment: For some reason, I can not connect to the database locally. I guess I should start there.

Comment: You need to setup a TNS entry.

Comment: I am setting it up now.