# Executable that runs a .sql file to prompt for a username to unlock in a oracle database. Needs to close at the end

Tags: sql, oracle, cmd, exe, sqlplus

I have an executable that connects to an Oracle database and runs a SQL script, stored in a ".sql" file. When the script runs, it prompts for a username input, and then unlocks it. After it completes the unlock and it pops up:

> User Altered with no errors

And it goes back to the sqlplus arrow.

I would want the window to close after the script has run. It works perfectly  on the remote server, without the connection details in the exe file. For some reason when I add the connection details in my exe to start sqlplus and run this script, it doesn't matter where I put exit at, or how I use it, the window still stays open.

Thanks for the help.

exe. code:

```
sqlplus system/password//server:1521/db @C:\Scripts\Script2.sql
```

sql code:

```
ALTER USER &user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
exit
```

Comment: Which 'window' are you referring to? Is it staying in SQL\*Plus (so you can type at the `SQL>` prompt I guess) - which shouldn't happen with the `exit` you showed? Or is SQL\*Plus exiting but leaving a wrapping command session running? Or something else? And how does it work perfectly on the remote server, without connection details - how does it run at all?

Comment: Unless... does `C:\Scripts\Script2.sql` exist on both the local and remote machines, and you've only added `exit` on the copy on the remote server? The SQL\*Plus client runs script files locally, it can't see files on the remote server...

Comment: I was being dumb. Sorry. Thanks for the input Alex Poole, I have it working now.

Comment: [An earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55228339/266304) said you this was for supervisors to run and "I could put the script on their computers and they could run it from their locations". This approach will expose the `system` password though, meaning any of those people could do whatever they wanted in the DB, basically. It would be [better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) to either grant `alter user` privs to their personal accounts, or have a stored procedure that issues the unlock, and grant execute on that to those users.